# How to access child type's properties in object of parent type in Go?

Tags: go

I am creating a file storage. I am trying to create different types of files. To simulate this, I use the code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type File interface{}

type Audio struct {
    File
    Duration time.Duration
}

type Image struct {
    File
    Width  uint
    Height uint
}

func main() {
    var files = map[string]File{
        "1": Audio{
            Duration: 14 * time.Second,
        },
        "2": Image{
            Height: 9989,
            Width:  1111,
        },
        "3": Image{
                        Width:  1234,
            Height: 5678,
        },
    }
    for k, v := range files {
        switch v.(type) {
        case Audio:
            fmt.Printf("%s: Audio %d seconds", k, v.Duration / time.Second)
        case Image:
            fmt.Printf("%s: Image %dx%d", k, v.Width, v.Height)
        }
    }
}
```

I am expecting this output:

```
1: Audio 14 seconds
2: Image 1111x9989
3: Image 1234x5678
```

But Go compiler gives me this error:

./main.go:38:44: v.Duration undefined (type File has no field or method Duration)
./main.go:40:39: v.Width undefined (type File has no field or method Width)
./main.go:40:48: v.Height undefined (type File has no field or method Height)

How to fix the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
switch v := v.(type) {
```

Will declare a new `v` with the type you are expecting.

Answer (score 3):

Simply assign the files to a variable before accessing them.

```golang
    for k, v := range files {
        switch file := v.(type) {
        case Audio:
            fmt.Printf("%s: Audio %d seconds", k, file.Duration/time.Second)
        case Image:
            fmt.Printf("%s: Image %dx%d", k, file.Width, file.Height)
        }
    }
```

You can simplify the given Go code by extracting the common parts outside of the type switch and using a format string to reduce redundancy. Here's a simplified version of your code:

```golang
for k, v := range files {
    switch file := v.(type) {
    case Audio:
        fmt.Printf("%s: Audio %s", k, formatDuration(file.Duration))
    case Image:
        fmt.Printf("%s: Image %s", k, formatImageDimensions(file.Width, file.Height))
    }
}

func formatDuration(duration time.Duration) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d seconds", duration/time.Second)
}

func formatImageDimensions(width, height int) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%dx%d", width, height)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this ,You have to do **type Assertion** ,See [here](https://go.dev/tour/methods/15)

```
 package main
    
    import (
        "fmt"
        "time"
    )
    
    type File interface{
    }
    
    type Audio struct {
      File
        Duration time.Duration
    }
    
    
    type Image struct {
      File
        Width  uint
        Height uint
    }
    
    
    func main() {
        var files = map[string]File{
            "1": Audio{
                Duration: 14 * time.Second,
            },
            "2": Image{
                Height: 9989,
                Width:  1111,
            },
            "3": Image{
                            Width:  1234,
                Height: 5678,
            },
        }
        for k, v := range files {
      
            switch v.(type) {
            case Audio:
                fmt.Printf("%s: Audio %d seconds", k, v.(Audio).Duration / time.Second)
            case Image:
                fmt.Printf("%s: Image %dx%d", k, v.(Image).Width, v.(Image).Height)
            }
        }

}
```

See working [link](https://goplay.tools/snippet/vIuDnmIE4xn)

Answer (score 2):

Try using this

```golang
for k, v := range files {
        switch f := v.(type) {
        case Audio:
            fmt.Printf("%s: Audio %d seconds\n", k, f.Duration/time.Second)
        case Image:
            fmt.Printf("%s: Image %dx%d\n", k, f.Width, f.Height)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. I just needed to use [type assertion](https://go.dev/tour/methods/15):

```golang
switch v.(type) {
case Audio:
    fmt.Printf("%s: Audio %d seconds", k, v.(Audio).Duration / time.Second)
case Image:
    fmt.Printf("%s: Image %dx%d", k, v.(Image).Width, v.(Image).Height)
}
```